# No sound on a clean install Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm new here, in fact im new on the linux world.

I've had some issues with ubuntu. Nothing that I couldn't managed to fix. But I'm having this problem with sound.

The first clean install I made sound worked perfect with pulseaudio eq, untill I installed some pluggins for TuxGuitar (MIDI sound, etc). And then my speakers just stopped working.

I did a reinstall of ubuntu 12.10 thinking it will fix the problem and it did. I installed pulseaudio and it was working fine, but 2 days later I got the same problem.

I've been searching through google and some threads here but I can't find the solution for my exact problem. And I've tried everything.

I'm adding a screen capture of Sound Settings in wich there's no sound drivers on the list (it had, but not anymore).. as you can see it's in spanish, but its only for illustration purposes ;)

[image]

I have a hp laptop.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type: "sudo alsamixer". Then make sure all bars are at 100%, and are not muted (MM). Otherwise, select the bar and press M.

Comment: I have sound now! But I can't mute or move the level. The taskbar displays the speaker icon with "--" beside it instead of the normal sound level indicator.

Comment: Pulseaudio is good, but is also know for being problematic in some hardwares. You could remove pulseaudio and use alsamixer instead. I can't ensure that this will work, but I think it's worth a try.

This page explains how to do it: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/01/how-to-remove-pulseaudio-use-alsa-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Removing pulseaudio seems like a bad idea: http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/07/13/top-five-wrong-ways-to-fix-your-audio/

Comment: Hmm, I tried removing pulseaudio the first time (before the full reinstal) and it didn't work. And according Takkat's posted website a little risky. I would like to find a solution without compromising OS stability.

Comment: Well, I'm using Linux Mint 14 with XFCE and Alsa Mixer, and it works just fine. This week Raring Ringtail will be realease, if you can, wait till 04/25 and try the new Ubuntu.

Comment: My solution for now its opening alsamixer through terminal and move the levels from there.. I guess I'll have to wait for new Ubuntu and hope the update would fix the problem! Thanks!

Comment: I hope it works for you :)